# How to customize tom-level properties in Spring boot and Swagger 2.0?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-2.0

Does anybody know how to customize tom-level properties in Spring boot and Swagger 2.0?

I tried use @SwaggerDefinition, but this does not appear to work.  Is there any mistake in my code below?

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "test" })
@EnableSwagger2
@SwaggerDefinition(info = @Info(title = "My Api Documentation",
  description = "My Api Documentation, Version:1.0",
  version = "1.0",
  contact = @Contact(name = "my name", email = "my_name@gmail.com", url = "http://my_page/") ,
  license = @License(name = "Apache 2.0", url = "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0") ) )
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

and I got the following json response from http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs

```
{
swagger: "2.0",
info: {
description: "Api Documentation",
version: "1.0",
title: "Api Documentation",
termsOfService: "urn:tos",
contact: {
name: "Contact Email"
},
license: {
name: "Apache 2.0",
url: "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"
}
},
host: "localhost:8080",
basePath: "/",
tags: [
{
name: "basic-error-controller",
description: "Basic Error Controller"
}
],
...
}
```

The top-level properties(title, discription) are supposed to have changed.

Comment: Improved the grammar to make the question more readable.

Comment: thanks a lot, I will try my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come to answer myself. 
I don't solve the problem about @SwaggerDefinition, but I found a alternative way.

I can overwrite Docket in my configuration class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "test" })
@EnableSwagger2
public class Application {

  @Bean
  public Docket confApi() {
    ResponseMessage msg_500 = new ResponseMessageBuilder().code(500).message("500 message").responseModel(new ModelRef("Error")).build();
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.GET, Collections.singletonList(msg_500))
        .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.POST, Collections.singletonList(msg_500))
        .apiInfo(new ApiInfo("My Api Documentation", "My Api Documentation, Version: 1.0", "1.0", null, "my_name@gmail.com", null, null));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```